# How to define json schema from nested arrays

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I'm working in Synapse and I need to define the JSON schema to read a stream, but I'm having some trouble getting to work. This is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "2023-07-02T09:00:00",
            [
                [
                    49.998,
                    1062
                ],
                [
                    49.993529,
                    1054
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            "2023-07-02T09:15:00",
            [
                [
                    49.982727,
                    1116.363636
                ],
                [
                    49.981176,
                    1093.117647
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "objects": [
        "inverters/3",
        "inverters/4"
    ],
    "indicators": [
        "frequency",
        "power.ac"
    ]
}
```

This is how I've tried to define the schema:

```py
    json_schema  = StructType([
        StructField("data", ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), containsNull=True), containsNull=True), containsNull=True), True),
        StructField("indicators", ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), True),
        StructField("objects", ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), True)
    ])
```

But it returns everything null in the data column with the warning that there is corrupt data, even though there isn't. I've tried just reading (without being a stream) and getting the inferred JSON schema and this is what I get:

```
    json_schema  = StructType([
        StructField("data", ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), containsNull=True), True),
        StructField("indicators", ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), True),
        StructField("objects", ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), True)
    ])
```

The problem with this is when I need to explode it doesn't know how to explode because it's defined as a string. What is the correct JSON schema for this type of data?

Comment: easiest way is to simply read normally, let spark generate the schema, then extract this schema as json.

Comment: Your schema is not valid according to spark. An array can only contains 1 type of data. and you mix both string and array inside `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the schema below to read the data:

```py
json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("data", ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), containsNull=True), True),
    StructField("indicators", ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), True),
    StructField("objects", ArrayType(StringType(), containsNull=True), True)
])
```

Use the following code to transform the data:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

tmp_df = df.withColumn("tmp", F.explode("data")).select("*", F.col("tmp").getItem(0).alias("timestamp"), F.col("tmp").getItem(1).alias("values"))
tmp_df = tmp_df.withColumn("values", F.explode(F.from_json("values", "array<array<double>>"))).withColumn("values", F.explode("values")).drop("data", "tmp")
tmp_df.show()
```

Output:

| indicators | objects | timestamp | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [power.ac] [power.ac] [power.ac] [power.ac] | [inverters/312e] [inverters/312e] [inverters/312e] [inverters/312e] | 2023-07-02T09:00:00 2023-07-02T09:00:00 2023-07-02T09:15:00 2023-07-02T09:15:00 | 1054.0 1090.17 1093.117647 2093.137 |

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer!
One thing that I forgot to mention is that I need to them explode taking into account the indicators and objects. The objects need to be traced to the vector position, so the first object is connected to the first array. And the same applies to the indicators, but is related to the positions inside the array, so the first indicator is related to the first position in the array.

Comment: Add your expecting results.

Comment: Do you mean  `[power.ac]` should have  `[49.998,1062  ]` and `[ 49.982727,  1116.363636],`

Comment: |  indicators |     objects  |           timestamp         |  values |
|-------------|-------------|-------------------------|---------|
|  frequency | inverters/3 | 2023-07-02T09:00:00 | 49.998 |
|  power.ac  |  inverters/3 | 2023-07-02T09:00:00 | 1062    |
|  frequency | inverters/4 | 2023-07-02T09:00:00 | 49.993529|
|  power.ac  |  inverters/4 | 2023-07-02T09:00:00 | 1054    |

Comment: No, inverters/3 should have [49.998,1062  ] and [ 49.982727,  1116.363636]. power.ac should have 1062 and 1116.363636. And frequency should have: 49.998 and 49.982727

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. Connecting multiple records based on position. Pyspark simply does explode making each record unique.

Comment: What do you think it could be a possible solution to this?? I need to be able to link them together, and I can't change the json format.
I've managed to do it once using zip:
df_exploded = df.select("*",expr("arrays_zip(values, value.values) as zipped"))
so I zipped the values that I wanted together and then exploded them, and that solved the problem. The problem here is more complicated because there's two entries that need to be zipped together.

Comment: yeah. here for `indicators`  and `objects` you get 4 combinations when exploded but with same `timestamp` and `values` so mapping those with required values is not possible.

Comment: I will update if there is any possible solution

Comment: Try this `tmp_df = df.withColumn("data",F.explode("data")).select("*",F.col("data").getItem(0).alias("timestamp"),F.col("data").getItem(1).alias("values"))

tmp_df = tmp_df.withColumn("values",F.from_json("values","array<array<double>>")).drop("data")

t = tmp_df.select("*",F.explode(F.arrays_zip("objects","values")).alias("z1")).select("*",F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.col("z1").values,"indicators")).alias("z2"))

t.select(F.col("z1").objects,F.col("z2").indicators,"timestamp",F.col("z2")['0'].alias("values")).show()`